# Log changes on the database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

A simple question. I´ve searching a whole week and found nothing about it.

It´s there any way of keep track of the changes on the real time database without having a client connected to observe changes?

Comment: If a tree falls in a forest and no one is around to hear it, does it make a sound?

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, I know that I need to observe the changes to keep track of them on my side. What I want to know is that if Google keeps track of all the changes made on the realtime database (like a file log)

Comment: Official answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43161522/is-it-possible-to-see-a-log-of-changes-made-to-firebase-db