# Is it possible to see a log of changes made to Firebase db?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

One of my firebase objects was deleted and I was trying to figure out when this happened.  Does Firebase have a log that shows you when the changes occurred?

Some people have said this exists in Analytics but i was unable to locate it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

*firebaser here*

There is no publicly accessible log of all changes that were made to your Firebase Realtime Database.